# Bootstrap offsetting does not seem to be working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with Bootstrap 3 and I have a grid system like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 offset-xs-4 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1">
       <img src="https://sitename.com/img/logo.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="offset-xs-4">
   </div>
</div>
```

And the result on `xs` devices goes like this:

[image]

But I want the logo to be placed in the center by using offset classes. Therefore I tried adding `offset-xs-4` to the class that contains logo and also added another div with `offset-xs-4` class after that.

But the problem is, it does not seem to be working and still shows the logo at the right side.

So the question is, how can I properly place this image in the center of screen when it comes to `xs` devices by using offset classes?

Comment: Your code and logic behind it is right. Based on what you're writing, that logo should appear in the center. I'm guessing that some other styling are 'hitting' that image as well. For instance, if the image is positioned absolute, with `right: 0;`. So if I was you, then I would inspect the elements and try toggling them on/off to see when the image got centerred. Uhh... And you could also be looking at this at a device-size that is not what you're aiming at. Perhaps try and remove: `col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1`

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 3 offset classes isn't `offset-xs-4`; it is `col-xs-offset-0`

I think you should confirm the Bootstrap version you are using and use the right documentation:

[Bootstrap 3 Offsetting columns documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting)

Comment: I just tried `col-*-offset-3` but still not working

Comment: no either put `col-md-offset-3` or `col-xs-offset-3`